# ¿Cuál es el origen de la expresión "oveja negra"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, etimología, historia, locuciones

En el DLE aparece [**oveja negra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=RLz2iBZ) como

> Persona que, en una familia o colectividad poco numerosa, difiere desfavorablemente de las demás.

Buscando el origen de la expresión he encontrado dos explicaciones:

- una, recogida en muchos sitios de internet (por ejemplo [aquí](https://www.definicionabc.com/social/oveja-negra.php), [aquí](https://uvejuegos.com/foro-aportacion/De-donde-vendran-o-por-que-se-diran-ciertas-expresiones/1598015/1#1598015) o [aquí](https://www.buzzfeed.com/beatrizserranomolina/pintar-la-mona?utm_term=.hkYR6V7wV#.nrO5mob9o)) indica que

  > "las ovejas negras no eran demasiado queridas en ningún rebaño, para el criador tener una oveja negra representaba una pérdida económica ya que su lana no estaba igual de cotizada en el mercado. Además, en Inglaterra en los siglos XVIII y XIX, el color negro de las ovejas era visto como una marca del diablo."
- otra, en el "Inventario general de insultos" de Celdrán Gomariz (1995):

  > El origen de este sintagma adjetivo parte de la confusión entre la palabra originaria, "arveja", y la hembra del carnero. La proximidad fonética entre los sonidos iniciales del término condujo a la errónea interpretación de un vocablo por otro, sobre todo cuando el término "arveja" empezó a caer
  >   en desuso, asimilándose en la mente del hablante con el de "oveja", más conocido y cercano a la experiencia rural. La arveja es voz que designa tanto al guisante como a la almorta. Ser la "almorta o arveja" negra es tanto como ser el garbanzo negro. Todo ello circunscrito semánticamente a las prácticas
  >   seguidas para decidir o votar premios y castigos, en cabildos y conventos. A fin de calificar a alguien, tanto moral como académicamente, los individuos con derecho a voto introducían en una bolsa negra un garbanzo, o una arveja; si la resolución era positiva, hacia el premio o hacia el "sí", la legumbre en
  >   cuestión era de color blanco; si se consideraba negativamente el asunto o persona, se introducía la arveja o garbanzo negro. Ser la arveja negra era tanto como distinguirse desfavorablemente. Hasta el siglo XVII se siguió en conventos, cabildos y congregaciones la costumbre de introducir en un tazón un haba, garbanzo o arveja negra entre el resto, que eran blancas. Quien sacaba la negra, pechaba, pagaba o se hacía cargo de la situación.

¿Cuál de las dos es la correcta? ¿Hay alguna otra explicación?

Comment: Since we use the same phrase in English then either (a) the first one is correct, (b) we borrowed it from Spanish. For what it is worth as a child i was always told the former as an explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

La historia de la arveja podría sonar plausible, pero fíjate el texto que acabo de encontrar en el CORDE:

> *E dixo la oveja blanca: - "Catad que pellejo trayo yo. Aquesto sinifica linpieza e honestidad que he de parte de dentro. E por esto valgo mas que ninguno de vos". Dixo la oveja negra: - "Yo so de fuera negra, menos preçiada; mas de dentro so fermosa. E aca en el mundo soy negra, e por esto menos preçio el mundo e lo tengo por suzio".*
>
> Anónimo, "Libro de los gatos", c1400 (España).

Nótese que estamos hablando de un texto, el *[Libro de los gatos](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Libro_de_los_gatos)*, escrito alrededor del año 1400, y ya entonces se tiene el concepto de la oveja negra como la oveja menos preciada del rebaño. Y no solo eso, sino que el texto original, escrito en latín, es de la primera mitad del siglo XIII.

No aparecen casos en el CORDE de "arveja negra". Sí que se encuentran expresiones ya por los siglos XIII y XIV de "no valer una arveja", en el mismo sentido que hoy día decimos "esto no vale un pimiento". Mas nada parecido a la historia de la arveja negra.

En mi opinión, creo que aquí deberíamos fiarnos un poco de la [navaja de Ockham](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Navaja_de_Ockham) y dar la explicación más sencilla como la más probable.